# How to display a button with “markup”?

Tags: 8, theming, forms, commerce, bootstrap-theme

I created a custom module and in the code below the button is not rendered, there is only the text :

```
$form = ['#markup' => '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">Product unavailable</button>'];
```

How to display the button?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Hook implementations of commerce_add_to_cart_access module.
 */

use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductType;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariationType;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

function commerce_add_to_cart_access_form_commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Your original code to get store owner.
  $current_store = \Drupal::service('commerce_store.current_store');
  $owner = $current_store->getStore()->getOwner();
  if (!$owner->hasRole('marchand_premium')) {
    // Overwrite the whole form markup!
    $form = ['#markup' => '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">Product unavailable</button>'];        
  }
}
```

Comment: if you change it to `'#markup' => 'Hello World'` do you see the text?

Comment: @NoSssweat  Yes it works, but I try to display the text in a button

Comment: If you remove/disable all CSS styles using [web developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm), or using some other tool, do you see the `Product unavailable` text?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [inline_template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21InlineTemplate.php/class/InlineTemplate/8.2.x) to solve the problem:

```
// Delete the other button.
unset($form);
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">Product unavailable</button>',
];
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85155/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-cid-almaguer-how-to-display-a-button-with-markup).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `commerce`, but I think you need to output a render array rather than actual HTML.

So replace `$form = ['#markup' ...` with something like the following:

```
// Add the new button to the form
$form['button'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Product unavailable'),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['btn', 'btn-success'],
    'disabled' => 'disabled'
  ],
];
```

See this link for what you can render with Drupal https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element/8.5.x

Comment: Thanks, with your code, the button is displayed but the module is broken. This answer does not work anymore if I apply your code https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271623/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-add-to-cart-button-for-products-based-on-the-role it shows the button "Add to cart" + the button ''Product unavailable"

Comment: Sorry not sure why the module would break with the above code, but to get rid of the duplicate button you can unset it - `unset(form['existing_add_to_cart_button'])`